# Get a fulfilled promise out of the function

Tags: javascript, typescript

maybe the is pretty stupid question but what is the way to go here?
I would like to create a function which returns to fulfilled promises from other functions?

```
getStorageData(){
    var result = []
    this.storage.get('ipaddress').then(ip => {
        result[0] = ip
        this.storage.get('timestamp').then(timestamp => {
            result[1] = timestamp
            console.log(result)
    })})
    return result
}
```

the console output is fine but the returned value of my defined function is an empty array. How do I get the output of the console to be the returned value of my function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a asyncrounous function:

```
this.storage.get('timestamp').then(timestamp => {
    result[1] = timestamp
    console.log(result)
}
```

Your script needs some time to get to `console.log(result)`. So the result is not defined at the place where you want to return it.

You could return it in the function body of the `.then()` function like this:

```
this.storage.get('timestamp').then(timestamp => {
    result[1] = timestamp;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Note: Don't forget the `;` at the end of a command.